# KendoGrid using selected checkbox without highlighting row

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using the KendoUi Grid (latest version) with AngularJS

I want to use the selectable feature on a column which shows a checkbox to (multi) select the row. This works fine.
But when the row is selected its colour changes. But I only want to use the checkbox without highlighting the complete row.

I tried to figer out which css I have to use.
This also works when setting the "**.k-grid table tr.k-state-selected**" css.
But when the mouse is over the selected row its still coloured. I tried to also set these "**.k-grid td.k-state-selected:hover, .k-grid tr:hover**" css, but it doesn't work.

Which css do I have to set, to disable complete the highlighting of a selected row.
This is my css I currentlc using. The part with the hover is not working.

```
.k-grid table tr.k-state-selected {
    color: red !important;
    background-color: none !important;
    background: none !important;
    border-color: none !important;
}

.k-grid td.k-state-selected:hover, .k-grid tr:hover {
    color: green !important;
    background-color: none !important;
    background: none !important;
    border-color: none !important;
}
```

*The red and green colour are just for testing, to see if its working ...*

**So, which css do I have to (re)set to disable the highlighting?**

Thanks

Comment: Is the goal to remove the select feature on the grid or just change the style?

Comment: I need the selected feature with the checkbox. I just want the row not to change the style when its selected.

Comment: Please try my answer. If you need you can addClass to your function

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function to the change event of your grid. Just add this to your grid definition.

```
change: functionName
```

Inside your function call:

```
$('.k-state-selected').removeClass('k-state-selected k-state-selecting');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with the removeClass. Now the highlighning is gone. As I wanted it. But now  internally the information which row is selected is also gone.

```
change: function(_) {
    var selectedRows = this.select(); 
    console.log(selectedRows.length);
}
```

**-> 1**

```
change: function(_) {
    $('.k-state-selected').removeClass('k-state-selected k-state-selecting'); 
    var selectedRows = this.select(); 
    console.log(selectedRows.length);
}
```

**-> 0**

So it seems the class is needed. And the only way is to overwrite the css information.